# Find recipient of a bitcoin transaction?

Tags: transactions, marketplace

Is there a way I can identify the recipient of a Bitcoin based on the transaction information? I have transferred Bitcoins a few years ago somewhere (possibly to Evolution marketplace, which was a scam) but I don't remember for sure where it went.

Comment: The transfer was made from Coinbase, in case this helps -- I can't find the information there though.

Answer (score 1):

Since the blockchain doesn't store user's IPs or any useful person tracking information, it's hard to track down the recipient of a transaction.

But I read on few forums how [Bitcoinstore](https://store.bitcoin.com/) owner tracked down a scammer to get the fraudulent refunded bitcoins back. You may come across a solution by studying this type of stories.

The details of the track down can be found [Here](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=131574.0;all#msg1409114)

Comment: Thanks, I just added as a comment that the transfer was made from Coinbase.